# Cannot find post paramaters in php

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, post, fetch

I am using `fetch` in `react native` application to send a post request as:

```
const data = {
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email'
  }
try{
    var r = await fetch(SEND_INITIAL_DATA, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers:{
       'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    });
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(r);
```

I am using php in my backend server. but I am unable to access the parameters in php and printing the `$_POST` is missing `body`

**PHP :**

```
<?php
require 'connect.php';

echo json_decode($_POST); // printing the post
```

**RESPONE**

[image]

What am I missing ?

Comment: you've to use json_decode !

Comment: I have updated my answer. Anyways response remains the same.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use `then` and `catch` in fetch for better debugging. example:

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(myJson) {
    console.log(myJson);
  });
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Change your code to:

```
const data = {
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email'
}

    await fetch(SEND_INITIAL_DATA, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then(function(response) {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
            console.warn(myJson);
        });
```

If you have an error, it will be printed and you can debug it.

Comment: It didn't make any difference. Actually, the problem isn't in the REQUEST, it's just that I am not able to access the post parameters in php.

Comment: is there any error before the dump ?

Comment: "It's better to use then and catch in fetch for better debugging" — That's subjective. Personally, I find `try`/`catch`/`await` to be far more readable. Recommendations for how to debug something are better left to comments rather than answers though.